# Synchronize time with C# application through Java

Tags: c#, java, ntp

I have a Java application running on Debian OS and communicate with a Windows C# server program. My Java application will connect to C# server program via TCP/IP. A problem I am facing now is that my Debian OS system time is always slower than Windows Server System Time. Both applications are mostly run in an internal network, which has no access to Internet.

1. May I know is there any way to synchronize the time between these two applications?
2. I read about NTP, can Java use NTP to synchronize time with C# program?
3. Must C# program be running as NTP Server? (Any way to do it?)
4. If writing simply message exchange between these two applications, will there be any problem?

Will be greatly appreciated if anyone can provide links to study the implementations.

Comment: Yes, Java can use NTP. Check out Apache Commons Net http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: What if both applications are running in internal network and have no access to Internet?

Comment: Can they communicate with each other over the internal network?

Comment: Yes, they can communicate with each other via private IP. Their ips are 192.168.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network should have *one* centralized NTP service against which *all* other clocks in that network precisely synchronize themselves.  Ideally, that NTP-server would synchronize itself against an Internet time-standard, but whether it does or not, **it** should be "the one and only source of Truth" for your entire network.

The old adage *literally* applies here:  "a man with one watch always knows what time it is; a man with two watches never does."

It is not appropriate for your application to attempt to manage time-sync, even if somehow it possessed the necessary privileges to do so.  *(And it **shouldn't**!!)*  Instead, it should require that the clocks of all systems must at all times be properly synchronized against one master source.  This should be its mandatory prerequisite, but not its personal responsibility.

Answer (score 4):

The best of all worlds would be to run your own local NTP server, and then sync both boxes to your local NTP server independently. You can even run the server on one of the boxes. Then you will have a common timing baseline from which to operate.

Alternately, if you have no access or support to do this, why not send the time in the data package that is transmitted between systems. Then, you will have the information needed to understand a differential between the machines. (This does not take into account any transmission delays between boxes, but it may be good enough to get the job done.)